# Windows batch script to continue in loop when scanning files in folder

Tags: batch-file

I need to convert all MP4 files in my subdirectories to MKV. So I wrote this script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET oldName=
SET newName=

FOR /r %%A IN (*.mp4) DO (
    SET oldName=%%A
    SET newName=%%A
    CALL :MAKEMKV
)

:MAKEMKV
SET newName=%newName:mp4=mkv%
IF NOT EXIST %newName% (
    START /B /WAIT ffmpeg -i "%oldName%" -map 0 -map -0:s -codec copy "%newName%"
)
```

The problem is that only first file in folder is converted and then it exits. But I use `for do` loop. So I could not get why it exits.

My structure is:

```
/FOLDER
../A/filea.mp4
../B/fileb.mp4
../C/filec.mp4
```

When I run above program I get only converted `filea.mp4` to `filea.mkv` and script exits.
The other files `fileb.mp4` and `filec.mp4` are not converted by the batch file.

What I am missing?

Comment: Note: `IF NOT EXIST %newName% (` will fail, if `%newname%` contains space(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read the help output on several pages.

There is no real need for a batch file as this task can be done from command line with:

```
for /R %I in (*.mp4) do @if not exist "%~dpnI.mkv" ffmpeg.exe -i "%I" -map 0 -map -0:s -codec copy "%~dpnI.mkv" && del "%%I"
```

The same command line from within a batch file:

```
@echo off
for /R %%I in (*.mp4) do if not exist "%%~dpnI.mkv" ffmpeg.exe -i "%%I" -map 0 -map -0:s -codec copy "%%~dpnI.mkv" && del "%%I"
```

I can't answer why your batch file fails because of not knowing the folder structure with real folder names and the real file names. But [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) is right with `IF NOT EXIST %newName% (` failing in case of file name with full path contains a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` because of not being enclosed in double quotes.

**Note:** `&& del "%%I"` results in deleting the just converted *.mp4 file if conversion was successful and `ffmpeg.exe` exited with `0` being usually the exit/return code for success. See also [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

And read also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) in case of ever writing once again a batch file with a subroutine. The batch file in question miss a `goto :EOF` or `exit /B` after the **FOR** loop to avoid a fall through to the subroutine code on **FOR** having finished. That would not be a problem here, but is in general not right.

Answer (score 2):

Using modifiers (see `for /?` or `call /?`), this is basically a one-liner:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r %%A IN (*.mp4) DO (
  if not exist "%~dpnA.mkv" (
    START /B /WAIT ffmpeg -i "%%~A" -map 0 -map -0:s -codec copy "%%~dpnA.mkv"
  )
)
```

(writen as multiline for better readability)

Haven't worked with `ffmpeg`, but probably you don't need thes `start` command:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /r %%A IN (*.mp4) DO (
  if not exist "%~dpnA.mkv" (
    ffmpeg -i "%%~A" -map 0 -map -0:s -codec copy "%%~dpnA.mkv" && del "%%~A"
  )
)
```

Added also code to delete the original `mp4`, if conversion was successful.